# simple json generation with php

Tags: php, json

currently i am using this

```
$big_test = array(
    'username' => 'test',
    'password' => 'test'

);

$test =  json_encode($big_test);    
echo $test;
```

the result is :

```
{"username":"test","password":"test"}
```

But I data to be wrap inside results,maybe liek this

```
{"Results":[{"username":"test","password":"test"}]}
```

Answer (score 5):

and what about to create as result array :

```
$big_test = array( "Results" => array ( array(
    'username' => 'test',
    'password' => 'test'
)));

$test = json_encode($big_test);

echo $test;
```

you get same thing what you put there

Comment: ok and how to print the decoded version ? $decode['Results']['password']; ??

Comment: ok anyway to search for specific results ? username = google ? using array search ?

Comment: Why the 3d array? a 2d would be 100% sufficient.

Comment: Yes it is sufficient, but take a look to what he wanted, there is associated -> unassociated -> associated. specific result search - se manual for php, i think it can be found there

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
$array = array("Results" => array('username' => 'test','password' => 'test'));
```